# Inject an AntBuilder using Spring?

Tags: spring, grails

I have code scattered through a Service in a plugin, using AntBuilder like this:

```
def ant = new AntBuilder()
```

This results in code that is really hard to test I'd like to inject a prototype-scoped AntBuilder that I can replace with a mock. But, I'm pretty much a Spring newbie ... how would I do that?

I tried simply putting this in /grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy:

```
beans = {
 antBuilderBean(groovy.util.AntBuilder){b ->
        b.scope="prototype"
    }
}
```

and

```
class MyService {
  def antBuilderBean
```

but antBuilderBean is null. If I put the bean definition in the *application*'s resources.groovy (rather than the *plugin*'s resources.groovy), then the bean name shows up in the application context, but antBuilderBean still resoves to null in the service code.

Do I need some sort of a factory bean here? Or, do I have to explicitly build the bean from the Spring context or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me in a new app just copy/pasting your code. Try running 'grails clean' - it often fixes issues with unexpected behavior like this.

Comment: Thanks!

I also found I could put the bean definition in the <my>GrailsPlugin.groovy doWithSpring() method.

Comment: Sorry, didn't catch that this was in a plugin - doWithSpring() is the place to register beans in a plugin.